# how to remove check from the checkbox if no files are selected to upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<label for="desktop_dimension_id">Desktop dimensions:</label>
            <span class="checkbox" id="desktopCheckboxId">
                <span class="checkbox_value">
                    <input id="dc1280_800" type="checkbox" name="1280x800"> 1280x800</span>
                    <input id="db1280_800" class="desktop_disabled" type="file" name="desktop_path_1280x800" size="100" />
                <span class="checkbox_value">
                    <input id="dc1366_768" type="checkbox" name="1366x768"> 1366x768</span>
                    <input id="db1366_768" class="desktop_disabled" type="file" name="desktop_path_1366x768" size="100" />
                <span class="checkbox_value">
                    <input id="dc1920_1080" type="checkbox" name="1920x1080"> 1920x1080</span>
                    <input id="db1920_1080" class="desktop_disabled" type="file" name="desktop_path_1920x1080" size="100" />
            </span>

        <input id="desktopCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1">Desktop
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var selected = $('#desktopCheckboxId input[type=file]');
        selected.change(function(){
            $('#desktopCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
        });
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BM29/)

Above is the code that checks the Desktop checkbox if any of the files is/are selected to upload. But the problem is I want to remove the check from the checkbox when no files are selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
selected.change(function(){
    $('#desktopCheckbox').prop('checked', this.files.length>0);
});
```

`this.files` is an array of selected files.

See my updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/8BM29/3/).

Comment: need to wait for few minutes before I'll be able to accept it.